# Install packages for python 3.x using pip

Tags: macos, python-3.x

My OS is Mac where the inbuilt python is 2.7 but I only want to use python 3.x.

Now I want to install some packages using pip for 3.x version, but the function pip is not defined in shell.

So how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with 3.4.0, the PSF Mac OS X installer installs pip by default.  If you do not have 3.4 already, I recommend that you install 3.4.2rc1 now or wait a few days or a week for the final 3.4.2 [download](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-342/).  And do check the mac and tkinter info link on that page.

Comment: I have installed 3.4.1. My problem is that the default python in mac terminal is still 2.7. Can I install pip for 2.7 and use it for 3.4? I doubt that would be the solution.